# Is my login form safe from sql injection?

Tags: authentication, php

```
$email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST[email]);
$pass = mysql_real_escape_strin($_POST[pass]);
$db_query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = '$email' AND password = '$pass' AND status = '1'");
```

Is there any possibility of getting my login form bypassed?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is my code using mysqli\_real\_escape\_string and quotes100% safe against SQL Injection?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/116670/) and [is 'mysql_real_escape_string' enough](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/47816/).

Answer (score 2):

Apart from that this is not even working (as `mysql_real_escape_strin` is probably undefined):

Please do use prepared statements. While I'm not currently able to produce input that breaks this, the functions you use are deprecated as per [php documentation](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php), where it says:

> Warning
>
> This extension was deprecated in PHP 5.5.0, and it was removed in PHP 7.0.0. Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension should be used. See also MySQL: choosing an API guide and related FAQ for more information. Alternatives to this function include:
>
> - mysqli_real_escape_string()
> - PDO::quote()

Comment: I agree with SmokeDispenser, you should use prepard statements for all SQL queries using user input as values to prevent SQL injection.